# Trying to upload a file in Cypress using cypress-file-upload, but no luck

Tags: typescript, file-upload, cypress

I was trying to use the following dependency (cypress-file-upload) to upload a file for a test case I am creating in Cypress.  However, I came across a thread of comments on [GitHub](https://github.com/abramenal/cypress-file-upload/issues) in which it states that the dependency is currently not working. Is there a workaround to this?  I currently write my test cases in TypeScript, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Does it show an error? For me it is working for cypres 6.8.0, since I wait for a stable version before migrating to 7+. I would try an older version or check if I did the correct migrations

Comment: @RosenMihaylov There is no error message. I am currently on version 6.8.0.

Comment: I had such problems with some plugins and fixed them at versions that are working. version 4.1.1 is working for me at cypress 6.8.0

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to upload a file in cypress:

1st - In your cypress directory need to create a fixtures folder.

2nd - You need to add here the files that you will use in your tests (json, csv, ...)

3rd - In spec file you need to save the POST answer in a variable like this

```
beforeEach(() => {
cy.route('POST', '**migration**').as('importMyFile');
```

3rd - Then add the following code

```
cy.get('input[type="file"]').attachFile('myFile_cypress.json');
```

4rd - Depending on your REST service you will already have to handle the answer that you have below. In my case is an HttpResponseBase, which is handled as follows:

```
cy.wait('@importMyFile').then(($prop) => {
            expect($prop.status).to.equal(200);
            Cypress.env('idMyFile', $prop.response.body.id)
        });
```

I hope it could be works for you :)